# StoryboardのNavigation Barの存在理由

Tags: ios, storyboard, navigationbar

`Storyboard`でUIを配置していく時に、画面右下から`Navigation Bar`を選択して`ViewController`に配置してみるのですが、`NavigationController`のナビゲーションバーのようになりませんよね？`ViewController`の上に配置しても`NavigationController`のナビゲーションバーと縦のサイズが違いますし、それに`Navigation Item`を引っ張ってきて配置しても`Navigation Bar`には反映されません。この`Navigation Bar`は一体何のためにあるのでしょうか？`NavigationController`のナビゲーションバーとは別物と考えたほうがいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Storyboardが登場してからは、ナビゲーションコントローラと中身のビューコントローラを一緒にInterface Builderで作ることができるようになったので、Navigation Barを単体で配置するのはレアケースだと思います。

使い方としては、ナビゲーションコントローラは必要ないけど、見た目を同じにしたいとか、上部にバーと閉じるボタンを配置したいとか、そういうときに使います。

特にStoryboardが登場する以前は、ビューに単体でNavigation Barを配置して、タイトルと左右にボタンを置いて、モーダルビューで表示する、といったときに簡単にInterface Builderだけで作れて便利とかそんな感じで使います。

似ている例を言うと、Search BarとSearch Display Controllerの関係とか。Search Display Controllerを使うほどじゃないけど、Search Barを置いて検索できるようにしたいというときはSearch Barだけ使う、のと同じです。

といったものなので、特に今までNavigation Barを使ったことがなくて、それで困っていないなら特に気にすることはありません。

ちなみに、ナビゲーションコントローラを使った場合と比べて高さが異なるというのは勘違いで、iOS 7からステータスバーと一体化した見た目になったのでそのように見えるだけで、ビゲーションコントローラを使ったときと同じ見た目にすることは可能です。
ビューコントローラにナビゲーションバーをステータスバーの高さだけ下げて設置して、デリゲートを接続して、そのデリゲートで下記のメソッドを実装します。

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar {
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

ここで`UIBarPositionTopAttached`を返すと、ステータスバーと一体化した見た目にしてくれます。

まとめると、今となっては単体で使うことはあまりないですが、必要ならナビゲーションコントローラを使わないときでも同様の見た目にしたり、ナビゲーションバーの機能を使うことができる、というためにあります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。なるほど、今やNavigation Bar単体ではあまり使わず、主に見た目を同じにしたいなどという時にNavigation Barを使うのですね。ずっとモヤモヤと気になっていたことが分かったのでスッキリしました！デリゲートでのステータスバーの見た目の変更も参考にさせていただきます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

既出の回答を補足する形で回答します。

NavigationBarの下のビューの背景色が、白色のとき限定の話ですが、NavigationBarを、StatusBarと一体化（したかのように）する、かんたんな方法は、下図のように、Attributes Inspectorで、**Translucent**のチェックを外すことです。見かけだけのテクニックですので、ちゃんとするには、既出回答のように、Delegateで操作してください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

NavigationBarには、ただひとつのNavigationItemだけ配置できます。Storyboardでは、NavigationBarのパーツには、最初からNavigationItemが配置されています。新たにNavigationItemをドラッグすると、既存のNavigationItemと入れ替わるだけです。
NavigationBar（の上のNavigationItem）に配置するのは、BarButtonItemです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Translucentのチェックを外すだけでは厳密にはステータスバーと一体化することにはなりません。下にあるビューの色を同じ色にすることで「そのように見えている」だけです。ビューの色とナビゲーションバーの色が異なるなら、一体化してるようには見えません。

Comment: @kishikawakatsumii ご指摘ありがとうございます。本文修正しました。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。Navigation Barにボタンなどを配置するのはNavigation Itemだと勘違いしておりました。だからNavigation Itemを配置しても入れ替わるだけで変化がないように見えたのですね。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

自分で設計したコンテナビューコントローラの部品として使うんだよ。UINavigationControllerのスタック方式のシングルビューじゃやってられんて時にコンテンツビューコントローラの管理方法を独自実装すんだよね？バーみたいなコマンドメニューを管理するカスタムビューまで作ってらんないからUINavigationBarやUIToolBarクラスを使うんだよ。UIAppearanceも使えてUINavigationController使ってる画面とも外観統一できて便利じゃない？

---

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。つまりナビゲーションバーがないViewControllerにUINavigationControllerのようなナビゲーションの機能を持たせたい時に使うということでよろしいでしょうか？しかしNavigation BarにNavigation Itemを追加しようとしても追加できず使えません。。。使い方が間違っていると思うのですが、一般的にはどういう使い方をするのでしょうか？

Comment: UINavigationItemならUINavigationBarに初めからひとつ配置されてます。その上にUIBarButtonItemをドロップすればleftBarButtonItemやrightBarButtonItemと接続されます。